# How to shrink my Android listview

Tags: android, listview, android-studio

So I have a basic app where a listview takes up the whole screen. Each line is a row number in text followed by two buttons `-` and `+` that will increment or decrement the number accordingly.

However I want to experiment with sizing, so I wanted to basically "shrink" this listview down to 1/4th size and have it work in the corner.

However I wasn't able to even shrink my original listview because all I can do is `fill_parent`, `match_parent`, or `wrap_content`.

What can I do?

My activity_main.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.doublebass.mylistapp.MainActivity">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

My attempt at using GridLayout (putting my real list in the upper left and the other four spots just empty, so I put in blank listviews):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.doublebass.mylistapp.MainActivity">

    <GridLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:columnCount="2"
        android:rowCount="2">

        <ListView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"/>
        <ListView
            android:layout_gravity="fill"
            android:layout_columnSpan="1"
            android:layout_rowSpan="1"/>

    </GridLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well ofcourse you have to do it programmatically. You have mentioned that currently the listview occupies the full screen. So, let's first get the height and width of the full screen:

```
DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
```

Now, when exactly do you want to resize your listview? There must be some user input or trigger. At that point, simply set the height and width as one fourth of that of the screen. You're done :)

```
ViewGroup.LayoutParams listParameters = listView.getLayoutParams();
listParameters.height = height/2;
listParameters.width = width/2;
list.setLayoutParams(list);
```

**PS:**

If you want to keep expanding/contracting the listview based upon some event, you just have to keep a global boolean variable which stores the current state. Toggle it everytime the state changes.

**How to do it using XML only**

The idea is to use the layout_weight attribute of `LinearLayout`:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="2">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Is it only possible programmatically? Right now I am experimenting with GridLayout but it isn't working. I'll update the OP.

Comment: Yes, if you want to expand/contract dynamically. But, if you just want to have it a fixed height and width all the time, why not mention your required height/width in xml itself? Or maybe I didn't get the problem.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I am just trying to squeeze the listview into 1/4th of the screen (so half its length, half its width)

Comment: Well, if you insist on using XML only for the changes, check the updated answer in a minute.

Comment: Your edit is much closer, but it seems to be taking up the top half rather than the upper left quadrant

Comment: Anyways, the idea is same. Play with the code, and you could have what you want.

Comment: Got it working; change to `android:layout_width="0dp"` in the ListView tag and it works. Please update so I can accept answer

Comment: oh, I missed that. Thanks for pointing out. Updated the answer.